# How to modify the controller scope from an ng-repeat in a directive, without using a function?

Tags: angularjs

I would like the ng-click to change the value of the controller scope variable 'controllerLabel'. What's the best way of achieving this without using a controller scope function?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <p>{{controllerLabel}}</p>     
     <my-template></my-template>
  </div>

    <!-- my-template.html -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="my-template.html">
        <div ng-repeat="clickLabel in clickLabels">
            <label ng-click="controllerLabel = {{clickLabel.text}}">{{clickLabel.text}}</label>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function Ctrl1($scope) {
        $scope.controllerLabel = 'Default text';
        $scope.clickLabels = [
            {'text':'Hello'},
            {'text':'World'},
        ];
    })
    .directive('myTemplate', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'my-template.html'
        };
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/camden_kid/4b4Hp/42/)

Comment: Do you want to use isolate scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle;
 [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4b4Hp/51/)

You need to use `controllerLabel` as an object property to have a shared object with controller.

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function Ctrl1($scope) {
        $scope.label = {};
        $scope.label.controllerLabel = 'Default text';
        $scope.clickLabels = [
            {'text':'Hello'},
            {'text':'World'},
        ];
    })
    .directive('myTemplate', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'my-template.html'
        };
    });
```

Template:
Note to `label.controllerLabel = clickLabel.text`

```
<div ng-repeat="clickLabel in clickLabels">
    <label ng-click="label.controllerLabel = clickLabel.text">{{clickLabel.text}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why an object works? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @camden_kid HTML looks for object under `$scope` and doesnt find it. But you can write `ng-init`: http://jsfiddle.net/4b4Hp/53/

Comment: Useful article for explanation of scope in angular: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 2):

You can add `link` to directive and write like:

```
.directive('myTemplate', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope) {

            scope.onClick = function (clickLabel) {
                  scope.controllerLabel = clickLabel.text;
              }
        },
            templateUrl: 'my-template.html'
        };
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-template.html">
        <div ng-repeat="clickLabel in clickLabels">
            <label ng-click="onClick(clickLabel)">{{clickLabel.text}}</label>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Actually you can write like @Alborz posted but I think to add method into link and call from HTML will be clearer and easy to debug.

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4b4Hp/49/)**</kbd>

Comment: I chose Alborz's answer as it was just a slight tweak to my code but I think your answer is very good and informative too. My basic knowledge of AngularJS means I can't say which is the 'best' answer.